# Checking if a filename exists and updating the file it in Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, mailmerge

I currently have a script which merges data from a Google Sheet into a Google Doc template. For each row of the worksheet, a new document is created using the title data from the row. The script works fine, but isn't my work. It has been passed onto me and I'm not skilled enough at Google Script to figure out what I'd like to achieve.

Ideally I wanted to know if it was possible to check when the script is run whether the document file already exists. It would do this as each document that is created uses the title data from the worksheet. If the document does exist then the data could be updated in that sheet, rather than creating a new version of it.

The script is the following

```
function mergeDocSheet() {
  const TEMPLATE_ID = '16YfyeDjGDp-88McAtLCQQyZ1xz4QX5z';// Google Doc template ID
  const SS_ID = '1C5gtJCSzHMuSz-oVWEItl2EUVRDwF5iH_'; // Google Sheet ID
  const SHEET_NAME = "data"; // Google Sheet Tab name
  const MAPPED = mappedDocToSheet; 
  const FILE_NAME = ["Titre de la formation"] // Header IDs from sheet.

  docMerge(TEMPLATE_ID,SS_ID,SHEET_NAME,MAPPED, FILE_NAME);

}

function docMerge(templateID,ssID, sheetName, mapped, fileNameData, rowLen = "auto"){
  //Get the Spreadsheet and sheet tab
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);

  //Get number of rows to process
  rowLen = (rowLen = "auto") ? getRowLen() - 1 : rowLen;

  //Gets the range of data in the sheet then grabs the values of the range
  const range = sheet.getRange(1,1,rowLen,sheet.getDataRange().getNumColumns());
  const matrix = range.getValues();

  // Searches the file mapped object and finds the corresponding number returns the column number in an array.
  const fileNameRows = getFileNameRows()


  //Loops through each row of the sheet grabbing the data from each row and putting it into a new doc.
  for(let i = 1; i < rowLen; i++){
    let row = matrix[i];
    //Get the title for the file.
    let fileName = buildFileName(row)

    let newDoc = DriveApp.getFileById(templateID).makeCopy(fileName);

    updateFileData(row, newDoc.getId());

  }; 

  function updateFileData(rowArray, doc){

    //Loops through the mapped object. 
    mapped.forEach(function(element){

      let textID = `\{\{${element.doc}\}\}`
 
      DocumentApp.openById(doc).getBody().replaceText(textID,
                                 rowArray[element.col]);
   });
  };

  function buildFileName(rowArry){

   let fileNameArray = fileNameRows.map(ele => rowArry[ele]);

   return fileNameArray.join("_");
  };


  function getFileNameRows(){
  //Map the column indexes from fileNameData
    let fileNameLocs = fileNameData
                      .flatMap(name => {
                        return mapped.filter(element => element.sheet === name)
                      .map(ele => ele.col);
  });

    return fileNameLocs;
  };

  function getRowLen(){
   return sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();
  };

};
```

Would it be possible to set up some kind of conditional, perhaps around these lines?

```
let newDoc = DriveApp.getFileById(templateID).makeCopy(fileName);

updateFileData(row, newDoc.getId());
```

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction with this. Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: In google drive it's possible to have identical filenames

Comment: I see, so in that case would it be impossible to check for a file that may have already been created with the same name?

Comment: [getFilesByName](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getFilesByName(String))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider using [searchFiles(params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchfilesparams) to search for a specific filename with Doc type in your drive based on the [search query term guidelines](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/ref-search-terms). Once you found all the files having the same filename, you can delete each file using [setTrashed(trashed)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#settrashedtrashed) before creating a new file using the template document

**Sample Code:**

```
  //Loops through each row of the sheet grabbing the data from each row and putting it into a new doc.
  for(let i = 1; i < rowLen; i++){
    let row = matrix[i];
    //Get the title for the file.
    let fileName = buildFileName(row);

    //This query parameter will search for an exact match of the filename with Doc file type
    let params = "title='"+fileName+"' and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.document'"
    let files = DriveApp.searchFiles(params);
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      //Filename exist
      var file = files.next();
      ///Delete file
      file.setTrashed(true);
    }
    
    //Create a new file
    let newDoc = DriveApp.getFileById(templateID).makeCopy(fileName);
    
    updateFileData(row, newDoc.getId());

  };
```

- In this given sample code, we will loop all files that have the exact filename and delete each file before creating a new one.

**Additional References:**

- [Google Drive Mimetypes](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/mime-types)

Comment: Thank you massively Ron for taking the time to write an in-depth answer. I really appreciate it. I suppose my first follow up question would be where to integrate code like this into what I already have?

Comment: Based on my understanding on your code, I agree on where you initially thought it should be placed. The checking should be done before creating a new file  `let newDoc = DriveApp.getFileById(templateID).makeCopy(fileName);`

Comment: I also tried to modify your code. please refer to the first sample code.

Comment: Ah yes, I see now. I will have to give this a go and see it can work for me. I suppose I would run the script without modifications to create the initial documents for each row. From then on, I would add this new script which, if it works, should only ever overwrite the existing documents.

Comment: Yes, please let me know if you will encounter some issues

Comment: Hi Ron, quick update. I ran the script without your conditional and a document was created, I then altered some data in the worksheet. 

I added your conditional to the code and then ran the script. The document wasn't created again, but the changes did not appear in the file so it wasn't updated. 

I then added another row to the sheet and no file was created but I expected that as the script is looking for duplicates by default, the originals should already be there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228853/discussion-between-adam-and-ron-m).

Comment: I see, It seems that the template doc has a specific `textID` that is being modified in `updateFileData` and since it was already updated once when you create the first file, it was not found anymore when you just want to update the file. How about we change your requirement that instead of updating the file is to delete the old file and create a new file using the template?

Comment: Yes, I would have no objection to that. Just another way of getting to the same place

Comment: OK let me verify first how to delete a file using apps script and i will update the answer

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate you taking the time on this

Comment: I updated the answer, please check and let me know if there are still some issues

Comment: There is some progress, I ran it with an empty drive, it created the file initially. I then made some changes to some row data and it has updated the file successfully without duplication. However, my worksheet does have 2 rows of information. But it seems only the first row is being read and it isn't looping the 2nd row. 

http://txt.do/18xit

Comment: is it also possible to share your template doc and your worksheet as well so i could check

Comment: can you share the file publicly, only for viewer permission, you can share the link in the chat that you created earlier. https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494822?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform=Desktop#zippy=%2Csend-share-google-forms%2Cshare-multiple-files%2Cshare-a-link-to-the-file%2Cshare-a-file-publicly

Comment: No, it requires me to request for an access. I am not allowed to do that. please share it publicly

Comment: OK, no problem, I will add public links in the chat

Comment: Please make sure to remove private information in your file temporarily, if there is any.

Comment: Hi Ron, I'm circling back to this as I'm trying to modify this script to it's original functionality. Which was to update the file rather than delete and create a new. Is updating the file possible to do in script? I know we had tried before and it didn't seem to work

Comment: Yes it will not work. When you first update the template file and search for specific tags for the first time, it should work. But once you were able to replace those search tags, you cannot find it anymore if you try to update the file for the 2nd time or for nth times

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. So even if I chose not to delete the file if it already existed, it still wouldn't be able to update the existing file?

Comment: yes. because you are trying to search for specific tags let textID = `\{\{${element.doc}\}\}` that were already replaced before

Comment: So is there no way of amending the current script in any way to achieve this? If they weren't getting deleted/replaced, only updating the original. The only reason I'm circling back to this is that I have recently found out that the generated Google Documents produced by the script will be linked to via a website. This means when one is updated, the URL /ID for that document will change and the web link will be broken.

Comment: It would be challenging to do that. You need to take note the old value that will be replaced and search that value in the current document. Of course there might be a slight possibility that there will be multiple search results. The easiest workaround is to just update the url/id as well in your website.

Comment: I'd hoped it would be possible to run the script, which would scan for docs using the same title, if one existed, it could then edit that document and continue through the loop. I have very little experience using Google Script in this way and if you say it's challenging then I'm not sure what chance I stand :)  it might need a rethink.

Comment: I have thought of another workaround, what you need to do is make a copy of the template document, update the contents of that copy you can call that as temp document.  Replace the body of the original document based on the template document. Then delete the temporary document. I'll try to replicate this on my end if this is feasible.

Comment: OK, I'm willing to try that. If you can replicate and get it working on your end that would be great, thank you.

Comment: Yes no problem. Do you mean ask another question?

Comment: Just posted    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66590714/creating-and-or-update-mail-merge-google-document-using-google-script   If you require the share links for the template and Google Sheet, perhaps I can send them through the chatroom, as I'd rather those links weren't public