# Creating and/or update mail merge Google document using Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, mailmerge

[(Continuation of another thread)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66231842/checking-if-a-filename-exists-and-updating-the-file-it-in-google-script/66232286?noredirect=1#comment117716281_66232286)

I currently have a Google Sheet with rows of data that I want to merge into a Google Document using a template file. Each row would be generate a new Google Document based on the template's layout. The script I am running currently will check to see if a file related to a Google Sheet row (using a title cell to match) already exists. If it does, then it will be deleted and a new document will be created in it's place with all of the changes made in the Google Sheet. If it does not exist a fresh document will be created.

However, I now need to link to these Google Documents from an external website. With the current script it means that if a change is made to a row in the spreadsheet, then it's corresponding document will be deleted and re-created, along with it's URL, thus making the website link useless and needing to be changed manually.

So ideally what I would like to achieve is rather than deleting and re-creating the documents, is to update the same document if it already exists. That way, the document gets updated and the URL will always be the same.

The script so far is this

```
    /*###################################################################
 * Create multiple versions of a document based on Google Sheet Data
 * and a Google Doc Template (Mailmerge)
 *###################################################################
 */

/*###################################################################
 * Main run file sets up variables for insertion into the mailMerge() 
 * function. 
 */
function mergeSheetDoc() {
  const TEMPLATE_ID = '16YfyeDjGDp-88McAtLCQQyZ1xz4QX5zEKAS09SaLkJI';//Add your Google Doc template ID
  const SS_ID = '1C5gtJCSzHMuSz-oVWEItl2EUVRDwF5iH_RVr6BxLkOU'; // Add your Google Sheet ID
  const SHEET_NAME = "data"; // Add your Google Sheet Tab name
  const MAPPED = mappedDocToSheet; // Go to Map.gs to update
  const FILE_NAME = ["Titre de la formation"] // Header IDs from your Sheet. Change to make your own file name.
  
  docMerge(TEMPLATE_ID,SS_ID,SHEET_NAME,MAPPED, FILE_NAME);

}

/** ###################################################################
 * Merges data from a Google Sheet into a newly created doc based on a 
 * Google Doc template. 
 * 
 * param {string} templateID: The id from the Google Doc template. 
 * param {string} ssID: The id of the Google Sheet. 
 * param {string} sheetName: the name of the sheet tab you are referencing.
 * param {object} mapped: Object array of data you mapped from your Doc template against your Google Sheet headers
 * param {array} fileNameDara: An array of data used to generate the file name. 
 * param {string} rowLen: (optional) If you want to add a number rows to create your merged documents.  
 */ 
function docMerge(templateID,ssID, sheetName, mapped, fileNameData, rowLen = "auto"){
  //Get the Spreadsheet and sheet tab
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  
  //Get number of rows to process
  rowLen = (rowLen = "auto") ? getRowLen() : rowLen;
  
  //Gets the range of data in the sheet then grabs the values of the range
  const range = sheet.getRange(1,1,rowLen,sheet.getDataRange().getNumColumns());
  const matrix = range.getValues();
  
  // Searches the file mapped object and finds the corresponding number returns the column number in an array.
  const fileNameRows = getFileNameRows()
  
  
  //Loops through each row of the sheet grabbing the data from each row and putting it into a new doc.
  for(let i = 1; i < rowLen; i++){
    let row = matrix[i];
    //Get the title for the file.
    let fileName = buildFileName(row);
   
    //This query parameter will search for an exact match of the filename with Doc file type
  let params = "title='"+fileName+"' and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.document'"
    let files = DriveApp.searchFiles(params);

    if(files.hasNext()){
      while (files.hasNext()) {
        //Filename exist
        var file = files.next();


        //Create a new file
        var tmpDoc = DriveApp.getFileById(templateID).makeCopy("tempfile");
        //Update the file
        updateFileData(row, tmpDoc.getId());

        //Copy contents of the new file to the existing file
        copyFileData(tmpDoc.getId(), file.getId());

        //Delete temporary file
        tmpDoc.setTrashed(true);
      }
    }else{
      //Create a new file
      let newDoc = DriveApp.getFileById(templateID).makeCopy(fileName);
    
      updateFileData(row, newDoc.getId());
    }
  
  }
};

  function copyFileData(sourceDoc, destinationDoc){
   var srcParagraph = DocumentApp.openById(sourceDoc).getBody().getParagraphs();
   var dstParagraph = DocumentApp.openById(destinationDoc).getBody().getParagraphs();
   
   for(var i = 0; i<dstParagraph.length; i++){

      //Paragraph Index of description and suivantes information
      if(i==5||i==21){
        
        dstParagraph[i].editAsText().setText(srcParagraph[i].editAsText().getText());
        dstParagraph[i].setAttributes(srcParagraph[i].getAttributes());
        dstParagraph[i].setLeftToRight(true);
        dstParagraph[i].setIndentFirstLine(srcParagraph[i].getIndentFirstLine());
        dstParagraph[i].setIndentStart(srcParagraph[i].getIndentStart());
        dstParagraph[i].editAsText().setFontSize(srcParagraph[i].editAsText().getFontSize());

      }
   }
 }
```

This code also references a mapping script which can be found here

https://textuploader.com/18xic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Workaround Summary:

- If filename already exist, create a temporary document that will replace the textId tags from the template document
- Copy the paragraph text and attributes of the temporary document to the existing document.

### Sample Modified Code:

Included only the modified/new functions.

```
function docMerge(templateID,ssID, sheetName, mapped, fileNameData, rowLen = "auto"){
  //Get the Spreadsheet and sheet tab
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  
  //Get number of rows to process
  rowLen = (rowLen = "auto") ? getRowLen() : rowLen;
  
  //Gets the range of data in the sheet then grabs the values of the range
  const range = sheet.getRange(1,1,rowLen,sheet.getDataRange().getNumColumns());
  const matrix = range.getValues();
  
  // Searches the file mapped object and finds the corresponding number returns the column number in an array.
  const fileNameRows = getFileNameRows()
  
  
  //Loops through each row of the sheet grabbing the data from each row and putting it into a new doc.
  for(let i = 1; i < rowLen; i++){
    let row = matrix[i];
    //Get the title for the file.
    let fileName = buildFileName(row);
   
    //This query parameter will search for an exact match of the filename with Doc file type
  let params = "title='"+fileName+"' and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.document'"
    let files = DriveApp.searchFiles(params);

    if(files.hasNext()){
      while (files.hasNext()) {
        //Filename exist
        var file = files.next();


        //Create a new file
        var tmpDoc = DriveApp.getFileById(templateID).makeCopy("tempfile");
        //Update the file
        updateFileData(row, tmpDoc.getId());

        //Copy contents of the new file to the existing file
        copyFileData(tmpDoc.getId(), file.getId());

        //Delete temporary file
        tmpDoc.setTrashed(true);
      }
    }else{
      //Create a new file
      let newDoc = DriveApp.getFileById(templateID).makeCopy(fileName);
    
      updateFileData(row, newDoc.getId());
    }
  
  };
 
 function copyFileData(sourceDoc, destinationDoc){
   var srcParagraph = DocumentApp.openById(sourceDoc).getBody().getParagraphs();
   var dstParagraph = DocumentApp.openById(destinationDoc).getBody().getParagraphs();
   
   for(var i = 0; i<dstParagraph.length; i++){

      //Paragraph Index of description and suivantes information
      if(i==5||i==21){
        
        dstParagraph[i].editAsText().setText(srcParagraph[i].editAsText().getText());
        dstParagraph[i].setAttributes(srcParagraph[i].getAttributes());
        dstParagraph[i].setLeftToRight(true);
        dstParagraph[i].setIndentFirstLine(srcParagraph[i].getIndentFirstLine());
        dstParagraph[i].setIndentStart(srcParagraph[i].getIndentStart());
        dstParagraph[i].editAsText().setFontSize(srcParagraph[i].editAsText().getFontSize());

      }
   }
 }
```

### What it does?

1. If filename was found, create a temporary document based on the updated information in the spreadsheet
2. Copy the specific paragraphs from the temporary document to the existing document
3. Delete the temporary document using [setTrashed()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#settrashedtrashed) method.

Comment: I seem to be encountering the following error 'ReferenceError: getRowLen is not defined' for docMerge or mergeSheetDoc. I have amended my intial post to show script my end

Comment: You need to include all your functions, I did not put the complete code in the answer. I just modified the docMerge() and define a new function copyFileData()

Comment: I see, and I can see it working, that's fantastic. I will test now with multiple rows and also test so that it creates documents for new rows

Comment: Noted, just let me know if you encountered any further issues

Comment: It seems to create new documents for new rows and update existing documents with updated content. It's working exactly how I need. Thank you so much again. I appreciate so much. It's great to see it working. Upvoted and answer accepted :)

Comment: No problem. Thank you

Comment: I do have a quick question if you don't mind. Looking over the code, I noticed this line: 'if(i==5||i==21)' which relates to the two cells in the sheet to merge across . Where is the 5 and 21 coming from? I'm not sure where to find these numbers in case I need to port across addtional columns in future

Comment: If you will print all the paragraphs that in the document file, the paragraph pertaining to the description and suivantes can be found in paragraph index 5 and 21

Comment: You can put Logger.log(srcParagraph[i].editAsText().getText()) inside the for loop to verify its content

Comment: I have put that logger code as the first line inside the for(var i = 0; i<dstParagraph.length; i++) loop but the execution log doesn't seem to be displaying any numbers when the script runs. Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: sorry please try Logger.log("index: "+i+" value: "+srcParagraph[i].editAsText().getText())

Comment: I see that makes much more sense. That will make it much easier to defne any other columns in future. Thank you

Comment: I just realized, be careful if you update your template and include additional paragraphs, you might need to adjust the index in this code as well. Its pretty much hard coded since its difficult to search for specific strings in the documents. You can include notes in your code for future reference

Comment: So if I was to include another column of data to add to the templates via another {shortcode}, it's likely the 5 and 21 index values would become redundant and need to be changed?

Comment: yes.  I hope the process of the workaround is clear. To copy specific paragraphs from source document to destination document.

Comment: Its seems clear. I know that there probably will be another column or two needing to be added to the template. I don't know which yet but when the time comes, I will have to change the 5 /21 or possibly add more into the if statement eg  if(i==5||i==21||1==40).  Would that be the only place it would need to be changed?

Comment: that is only for the update when trying to copy updated template to existing document. You might need to modify some of your function if you included additional tags in your template like the updateFileData()

Comment: So if I wanted to add an additional column from the spreadsheet, the first thing I would need to do is add the column details to Map script. Then, in the script itself I would add the paragraph index to the conditional (5, 21 etc). As long as these things are added, to the script as well as the shortcode to the template. Would this be enough to run the script successfully?

Comment: The updateFileData function simply loops through the mapped objects so as long as the extra data is added there it should be OK